# How to specify to use a specific PHP version when running "composer install"?

Tags: php, composer-php, php-7.2, php-7.4

In a server we have a few of webapp and actually have both 7.2 and 7.4 installed.

When running composer install, it use the PHP setup as default in the system, actually the 7.4.

In fact,

```
$ which php
/usr/bin/php

$ php -v
PHP 7.4.2 (cli) ...

$ ls -la /usr/bin/php
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 21 Nov 20 11:20 /usr/bin/php -> /etc/alternatives/php

$  ls -la /etc/alternatives/php
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 15 Feb 12 11:08 /etc/alternatives/php -> /usr/bin/php7.4
```

The app were I must execute `composer install` is a PHP 7.2, so I need the composer respect this.

I am sure it trying to use PHP 7.4 because it is complaining about `php7.4-mbstring` missing. But it's installed and enabled for PHP 7.2.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is more than one issue here.

First, you most likely don't really need to tell `composer` to use one interpreter or another. If you **know** that the platform requirements are going to be correct at runtime, but the runtime executable is not the same than the `install` executable, you can simply say:

```
composer install --ignore-platform-reqs
```

This way composer won't check that the runtime and extensions match what you declared on `composer.json` (but you'll need to make sure that these requirements are fulfilled on the server where the project actually runs).

---

But if you really want to execute composer with a different runtime...

`composer` uses [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) + `env` to determine which PHP executable is going to use.

Basically it uses `#!/usr/bin/env php` to find which `php` executable is available, same as you were doing.

If you want to use a different executable, you just need to be explicit about it.

E.g. if your PHP 7.2 is installed at `/usr/bin/php7.2` and composer at `/usr/local/bin/composer`, you just need to do:

```
# /usr/bin/php7.2 /usr/local/bin/composer install
```

Comment: Doing that I'm getting this output: "Status: 501<newline>Content-type: text/plain<newline><newline>Not supported"